# Closing questions too soon

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Poorly formulated questions - close and re-open or delay closing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108359/poorly-formulated-questions-close-and-re-open-or-delay-closing)

I have noticed that there have been some questions where it was a poorly worded question, but could have been improved if more detail was provided, or were clearer in what they were asking.  Before I could edit or make a suggestion, it would be closed.  This is often happening less than 10 minutes after the question was asked. Is there any way that the mods can wait before the question is asked so that the user can clean up their question?

Comment: You have a preview function, there you can improve your question before sumbitting.

Comment: This is after submitting the question, and often a new user asking the question.

Comment: @CBredlow His point was that if the question was that bad, and you were capable of improving it, you shouldn't have submitted it in the first place.  You should have waited until you were ready to first submit it.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets 6,000 new questions a day. Do you seriously expect people to wait for 10 minutes before closing a bad question, while the OP could simply have written a useful question before posting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let questions stay open for a minimum amount of time before being closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/let-questions-stay-open-for-a-minimum-amount-of-time-before-being-closed) and [Poorly formulated questions - close and re-open or delay closing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108359/poorly-formulated-questions-close-and-re-open-or-delay-closing)

Comment: WATCH OUT @CBredlow, THE CLOSE / NEG PATROL IS ABOUT TO HIT YOUR QUESTION TOO! RUN, QUICKLY!

Comment: It's closing her...then they're going to close me... OH MY GOOOOOOODDDD!! No seriously though. I've seen the error of my ways with Servy's answers and Pekka's comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closed != deleted.

Closing a question doesn't mean it can't be edited.  It doesn't mean that people can't post clarifying questions to the author, or provide constructive feedback as to what aspects of the post need to be improved or expanded on.

It doesn't delete any existing answers, or prevent them from being improved through comments or edits.

And finally, closing can be reversed (quite easily) through reopen votes.

The idea of closing a question is to give an opportunity for the asker to fix that question.  If they fix the question it can be re-opened.  If they don't, it may end up being deleted if it's clear that it can't be or won't be improved.