# The fate of closed Questions

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

What is the fate of closed Qs?

Are they eventually deleted from the site or not?

Suggestion: Shouldn't there by a penalty  for the user asking the Q when his Q ends up closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed questions never gets deleted(as far as I've seen), unless they're voted for deletion.

The question asker often gets penalty in terms of negative votes from other users, so no other penalty required. Sometimes the closed questions to attract positive vote. So it's completely on the user community whether they want to penalize the asker or not.

More info on [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/178982) about deletion of closed questions.

Comment: Unless of course if it's a spam question. Then mods take care of it.

Comment: Not only closed question, but if any question meet the criteria: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006 it will be automatically cleaned up.

Comment: I thought that to (that they didn't get deleted). But why keeping a Q in the site if it is considered not helpful for the community (since it have been voted closed)

Comment: Closed does not necessarily mean non-helpful

Comment: Closed questions are helpful, since they can provide good info on why it has been closed and what if someone wants to ask the same question again. The closed questions can be reopened again, at any time, if sufficient reopen votes has been gathered. So no point in deleting them. If it needs deletion there's separate voting for that. Closed questions are closed for answers, they're kinda in read only mode. They don't need to be deleted.

Comment: Read the answer I linked, it explains the philosophy in detail.

Comment: @apomene question closed as Off Topic or Not a Real Question [already get automatic downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84978/152859).

Comment: Another helpful discussion about closed questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70061/i-propose-changing-the-term-closed-out-for-something-else?lq=1